# Why don't my Broadcom modules automatically load?

Tags: wireless, broadcom, modprobe

At work I was given a Dell Lattitude E6320 laptop (64-bit) with Windows 7 installed on it. I used it for a few months (with no problems using wired or wireless networking) and then decided to gut the OS and replace it with Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. And I loved it.

The only problem was: I lost (or thought I lost) all wireless capabilities. All of the sudden, wireless was disabled on my machine, and as such, I couldn't find any of the wireless networks I was used to using.

Last week, a co-worker recommended trying `sudo modprobe wl` because he thought it might be my Broadcom wifi drivers; I gave it a try **and it works**. So now, in order to have wifi, I need to run `sudo modprobe wl`.

Why (specifically)? Are these drivers not supported in the Ubuntu repositories for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

The module is present on your OS (seeing as how modprobe loads it), but it appears to not load on boot, could be due to an upgrade or something like that.

Either way, first check if the specific module is blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, if so, comment out the line containing it (just add a # at the beginning of it).

If it's not blacklisted and still fails to load on boot, add the module to /etc/modules